# Esp32 and 74hc595 problem

Tags: arduino-mega, esp32

I am using 74hc595 in several projects where I need more I/O and always worked fine using arduino pro mini or arduino mega. Now I connected same 2 of 74hc595 to an esp32 and does not work.
Is there any special things to do for esp32?

Wiring is exactly the same like here https://www.arduino.cc/en/tutorial/ShiftOut on chapter 2 (Connect the 2 registers.). If I use this with an arduino mega on pins 10,9,8 (see commented in code) is working perfect.

Then I replace arduino mega with esp32 and using pins 23,18,5 and does nothing. I get in serial monitor on/off prints but nothing changes to the relays.

Code

```
int SER_Pin = 23;//10; //pin 14 on 75hc595 //data pin
int RCLK_Pin = 18;//9; //pin 12  //latch
int SRCLK_Pin = 5;//8; //pin 11  //clock

#define number_of_74hc595s 2

#define numOfRegisterPins number_of_74hc595s * 8

boolean registers[numOfRegisterPins];


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(SER_Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RCLK_Pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(SRCLK_Pin, OUTPUT);

  clearRegisters();
  writeRegisters();
}

void clearRegisters() {

  for (int i = numOfRegisterPins -1; i >= 0; i--) {
    registers[i] =HIGH;
  }
}

//Set and display registers
//Only call after all values are set how you would like
void writeRegisters() {
   digitalWrite(RCLK_Pin, LOW);

   for (int i = numOfRegisterPins -1; i >= 0; i--) {
      digitalWrite(SRCLK_Pin, LOW);
      int val = registers[i];

      digitalWrite(SER_Pin, val);
      digitalWrite(SRCLK_Pin, HIGH);
}
  digitalWrite(RCLK_Pin, HIGH);

}

//set an individual pin high or low
void setRegisterPin (int index, int value) {
  registers[index] = value;
}

void c_on() {
  Serial.println("on");
  setRegisterPin(13,LOW);
  writeRegisters();
  delay(50);
}

void c_off() {
  Serial.println("off");
  setRegisterPin(13,HIGH);
  writeRegisters();
  delay(50);
}

void loop() {

c_on();
delay(1000);
c_off();
delay(1000);

}
```

Is there any special thing to do for using esp32?

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you powering the shift registers from 5V or 3.3V?

Comment: What relays are you using? Are you sure they work with the voltage you are powering your shift registers with? If you connect an LED+resistor to the shift register pin you are testing (#13 according to your code), does it light up?

Comment: the speed is different. maybe add some short delay in micros after setting the SRCLK

Comment: @Juraj, one single microsecond should be more than enough for the HC595.

Comment: The issue was from the power supply. Weird because same power supply worked with arduino mega

Comment: WiFi requires more current